# Z3 Prover Increase Time and Memory in Command Line

Tags: z3

I'm trying to verify that 003-23-80.cnf is satisfiable using Z3Prover. I've already verified it is satisfiable using Minisat, but it took around 2 hours and 500 MB of memory.

In bash I wrote:

z3 -wcnf -st -T:9000 -memory:500 003-23-80.cnf

I believe this should extend the time to 9000 seconds and memory to 500 Megabytes, but my output is unsat:

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmZJX.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of memory/time etc.; if minisat is saying this benchmark is `sat` and z3 is saying it's `unsat`, then one of them has a bug! Depending on which one is actually expected, you should report this as a bug to the faulty party. (If you are not sure, just report to z3 folks indicating they disagree with minisat. Use the issue tracker here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues)